# NSFetchedResultsController performFetch slow with many returned items

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm building an application that implements a live text search which queries the database whenever a text input changes.
It works but the keyboard input is laggy when the NSFetchedResultsController's fetchRequest returns more than a certain amount of items ( > ~20 ).

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate("itemID" > 0) //<- returns all items
    self.frc.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    self.frc.executeFetchRequest(nil)
}
```

Notice that there's no actual UI update going on so the laggy keyboard input must be caused by the fetchRequest.

Is there a way to implement live search with high amounts of items without this lag?

Comment: It seams your predicate does not change. What is the use of fetching all items on every key press?

Comment: The example code is the result me narrowing the problem down to just fetching the items. In the actual project the predicate changes and the UI updates to display the new data

Comment: One solution is to only start fetching once there are at least 2 characters.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are performing the fetch on the main thread and load all the objects with your request. Do you really need all the items loaded? As a first step, set a `fetchBatchSize` to have only few items actually load in the memory, and as you scroll in your view, some items will be loaded automatically and others faulted. If this is not enough, consider a design change, where you should move the actual fetch to a background queue, and just update your UI when results are in. This is a big change, as you have to cancel previous ongoing request if the user invalidates the search context (i.e. he types a new character).

Comment: Could you provide a quick example on how to perform a fetch on a background thread and how to cancel an ongoing request?

Comment: It's not a simple task at all, and requires a major change in functionality.  Explaining it as part of an answer would take a very long time. That is why I recommend starting with `fetchBatchSize`. 70 objects sounds like a small size to actually stall the main thread if managed properly. If you still need to go the hard way, I suggest reading about Core Data multithreading using parent-child contexts and `NSOperationQueue` and operations.

Comment: setting a fetchBatchSize does not improve performance at all even though setting a fetchLimit does which would lead me to expect setting fetchBatchSize would have a very similar effect.

Comment: Have you tried running Instruments to see what takes the most CPU time?